# How to build a Protobuf request out of a json message?

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers

I maintain a small protobuf based REST-ful API using Jersey. I am working on a small project that can call protobuf api via json proxy endpoint. To illustrate my idea, here is the list of resources and endpoints:

```
PersonResource
    GET /getPerson -> @returns instance of PersonProto
    POST /person -> create person and @returns instance of PersonProto
SubscriptionResource
    GET /getSubscriptions(personId) -> @returns List<SubscriptionProto>
etc
```

Now using a postman like client, user can hit a protobuf request via a json proxy endpoint by passing a json request instead of protobuf message. So i d like my proxy endpoint to handle back and forth conversion between json and protobuf. Is there a reliable way to do it using Java 11 and Protocol-buffers version 3? If so could you share please some examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to access protobuf objects and create mapping between protobuf and json.

Comment: Thanks @talex. What do you mean by mapping ? Could you provide an example ? Yeah I was thinking to use JSONFormat with reflection.

Comment: You basically iterate through json properties, find corresponding protobuf properties via reflection and assign values to them.

Comment: Yeah that's what JSONFormat does. Thanks if you find some examples i ll be happy to take a look

Answer (score 0):

I knew we could use reflection from the beginning but I thought there may be a simpler way exist to accomplish the same. Here is the helper class that I produced for such use-case:

If you know the path to a message class or have reference to a message class somehow, then you can use JsonFormat utility of protobuf.

```
package com.apple.amp.commerce.support.protodive.util;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException;
import com.google.protobuf.Message;
import com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat;

import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class ProtoBufJsonSerializer {

    private static final JsonFormat.Parser JSON_FORMAT_PARSER = JsonFormat.parser().ignoringUnknownFields();
    private static final JsonFormat.Printer JSON_FORMAT_PRINTER = JsonFormat.printer().includingDefaultValueFields();
    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    public JsonNode getJsonNodeFromMessage(Message message) {
        final String jsonString = getJsonStringMessage(message);
        try {
            return OBJECT_MAPPER.readTree(jsonString);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

    private String getJsonStringMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            return JSON_FORMAT_PRINTER.print(message);
        } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to transform message to json", e);
        }
    }

    public Message getMessageFromJson(String messageClassName, JsonNode requestPayload) {
        Message.Builder msgBuilder = getMessageBuilder(messageClassName);
        try {
            String jsonString = requestPayload.toString();
            JSON_FORMAT_PARSER.merge(jsonString, msgBuilder);
            return msgBuilder.build();
        } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    private Message.Builder getMessageBuilder(String messageClassName) {
        try{
            Class<? extends Message> msgClass = (Class<? extends Message>) Class.forName(messageClassName);
            Method toBuilderMethod = msgClass.getMethod("getDefaultInstance");
            Message msg = (Message) toBuilderMethod.invoke(null);
            return msg.toBuilder();
        } catch(IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to transform json into message", e);
        }
    }
}
```